# Write code and explain some term in Logistic regression analysis by R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

We want to do the logistic regression analysis to consider the effect of Age, CD4 on drug resistance mutations. The code that we wrote is:

```
logist.summary(glm(DRM ~ Age, data = Database, family = binomial),"wald")
```

The results are:

```
            log.OR OR lower.CI upper.CI p.value
(Intercept)  -0.31 0.74     0.05     9.95  0.8169
Age          -0.07 0.93     0.86     1.00  0.0525
```

However, we want to do the test like, we will consider whether, 20 years old differences between the subjects, what the results is? Is it relative to DRMs? We wrote:

```
logist.summary(glm(DRM ~ I(Age+20), data = Database, family = binomial),"wald")
```

Results:

```
            log.OR   OR lower.CI upper.CI p.value
(Intercept)   1.17 3.22     0.05   190.62  0.5742
I(Age + 20)  -0.07 0.93     0.86     1.00  0.0525
```

I want to ask:

- Is the code we wrote correct?
- Can you help me explain what is meaning of these table?
- Why it is the same results for the Age and Age+20? But differences in the Intercept? What does intercept meaning in this case?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you help me explain what is meaning of these table?
>
> Why it is the same results for the Age and Age+20? But differences in
>   the Intercept? What does intercept meaning in this case?

I'm using an example here based on linear regression, but the concept can be generalized to logistic regression.

Here we add a constant of 20 to the independent variable `mpg`. Both regression lines using the original and the new one with extra 20 are shown:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen mpg20 = mpg + 20
twoway (lfit price mpg) (lfit price mpg20), xtitle(Mile per gallon) ///
  legend(label(1 "Origianl") label (2 "Original + 20")) scheme(sj)
```

[image]

As you can see, adding a constant to the independent variable merely moves to the line horizontally with out changing the slope. So, that's why your slopes are the same.

As for the intercept, if you lengthen the lines in the illustration, you'll see them hitting the y-axis (aka intercept) at different points. That's why your intercepts are different. As to what does it mean for an intercept of 1.17 in your model 2, it's the predicted logit of even when your (age + 20) = 0, in other words, when age = -20.

---

> [...] we want to do the test like, we will consider whether, 20 years
>   old differences between the subjects [...]
>
> Is the code we wrote correct?

No, it's not the correct code to answer that question. There is a couple ways to do that. First, you may use contrast to test the coefficient of `Age` in model 1 versus 20 times the same coefficient. Another simpler way is to change your age's unit to "20-year" by dividing them age with 20 (not add.)

Here is the same example using original mpg:

```
. gen mpgInUnit20 = mpg / 20
. 
. reg price mpg

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,    72) =   20.26
       Model |   139449474     1   139449474           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |   495615923    72  6883554.48           R-squared     =  0.2196
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.2087
       Total |   635065396    73  8699525.97           Root MSE      =  2623.7

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -238.8943   53.07669    -4.50   0.000    -344.7008   -133.0879
       _cons |   11253.06   1170.813     9.61   0.000     8919.088    13587.03
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. reg price mpgInUnit20

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,    72) =   20.26
       Model |   139449477     1   139449477           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |   495615919    72  6883554.43           R-squared     =  0.2196
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.2087
       Total |   635065396    73  8699525.97           Root MSE      =  2623.7

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 mpgInUnit20 |  -4777.887   1061.534    -4.50   0.000    -6894.016   -2661.758
       _cons |   11253.06   1170.813     9.61   0.000     8919.088    13587.03
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first model's coefficient -238.9 corresponds to the unit of "mile per gallon." The second model's coefficient -4777.9 corresponds to the unit of "20 miles per gallon." The p-value of `mpgInUnit20` is then testing if an increment of 1 "20 miles per gallon" is statistically significant.

---

Lastly, please double check your sample sizes in the two model, from your coefficient it seems the difference is something closer to 21 years instead of 20.

Comment: The other way would be to use the model @user78617 fitted would be to *plot* the marginal effect of age. In R, that'd be using the `predict` function, or more straightforwardly, the [effects](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) package.

Comment: Would you like to help me write the correct code for 20 years old differences by logistic regression model in R?

Comment: @user78617, the `gen mpgInUnit20 = mpg / 20` is equivalent to `mpgInUnit20 <- mpg / 20` in R. You just need to divide your age by 20, and use that new age variable as the independent variable instead of age in year.